Repairing built-in blinds
Found the blinds completely crooked and dismantled on one of the doors. The string was broken and I suspect of the kids were up to some mischief.
Is there any way to repair this myself - if not, what are my options? I don't see any screws along the trim nor any screw caps. The 'operator' has come loose and I don't feel the magnetics along the track.
One of the slides say Novatech Discretion and I've uploaded some photos.



Novatech Discretion comes with a ten-year warranty.  Call them up and ask if this is covered.  If not, ask how to get to the blind.
